# Asp.Net Windows form run time Error - "Procedure or function Insert has too many arguments specified."

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Windows Form : [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/We2Wg.png)

Error : [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5jdW.png)

I create a Windows Forms application, but whenever I submit the form, I get an error.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication12
{
   public partial class Add : Form
   {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=AMAR;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";

        public Add()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PhoneNo_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char ch = e.KeyChar;

            if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
            {
                 e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void Pin_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            char ch = e.KeyChar;

            if (!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch != 8)
            {
                 e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

    private void cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Stat = Status.Text;
        string FirstName = FName.Text;
        string LastName = LName.Text;
        string Address = Addr.Text;
        string Cities = City.Text;
        string States = State.Text;
        string Countries = Country.Text;
        string PhoneNos = PhoneNo.Text;;
        string EmailId = Email.Text;
        string PinCode = Pin.Text;
        string CIn = CheckIn.Text;
        string COut = CheckOut.Text;
        string AdultNo = Adult.Text;
        string ChildNo = Child.Text;
        string InfantNo=Infant.Text;
        string RoomNos=RoomNo.Text;

        TestObject obj = new TestObject();

        obj.Stat=Status.Text;
        obj.FirstName = FName.Text;
        obj.LastName = LName.Text;
        obj.Address=Addr.Text;
        obj.Cities=City.Text;
        obj.States= State.Text;
        obj.Countries =Country.Text;
        obj.PhoneNos= PhoneNo.Text;;
        obj.EmailId= Email.Text;
        obj.PinCode=Pin.Text;
        obj.CIn=CheckIn.Text;
        obj.COut=CheckOut.Text;
        obj.AdultNo=Adult.Text;
        obj.ChildNo=Child.Text;
        obj.InfantNo=Infant.Text;
        obj.RoomNos=RoomNo.Text;

        string spName = "Insert";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);

        conn.Open();

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stat", obj.Stat);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", obj.FirstName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", obj.LastName);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", obj.Address);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cities", obj.Cities);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@States", obj.States);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Countries", obj.Countries);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneNos", obj.PhoneNos);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailId", obj.EmailId);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PinCode", obj.PinCode);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIn", obj.CIn);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COut", obj.COut);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdultNo", obj.AdultNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ChildNo", obj.ChildNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InfantNo", obj.InfantNo);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNos", obj.RoomNos);

        com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}

public class TestObject
{
    public string Id;
    public string Status;
    public string FName;
    public string LName;
    public string Addr;
    public string City;
    public string State;
    public string  Country;
    public string  PhoneNo;
    public string  Email;
    public string Pin;
    public string CheckIn;
    public string  CheckOut;
    public string  AdultNo;
    public string  ChildNo;
    public string InfantNo;
    public string RoomNo;
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string States { get; set; }
    public string Countries { get; set; }
    public string Cities { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNos { get; set; }
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
    public string PinCode { get; set; }
    public string CIn { get; set; }
    public string COut { get; set; }
    public string RoomNos { get; set; }
    public string Stat { get; set; }}
}
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Insert] 
    @Stat nvarchar(100),
    @FirstName nvarchar(100),
    @LastName nvarchar(100),
    @Address nvarchar(100),
    @Cities nvarchar(100),
    @States nvarchar(100),
    @Countries nvarchar(100),
    @PhoneNos int,
    @EmailId nvarchar(100),
    @PinCode int,
    @CIn nvarchar(100),
    @COut nvarchar(100),
    @AdultNo int,
    @ChildNo int,
    @InfantNo int, 
    @RoomNos int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    INSERT INTO [Hotel].[dbo].[Details](Status, FirstName, LastName, Address, City, State, Country, PhoneNo, CheckIn, CheckOut, EmailId, Pincode, AdultNo, ChildNo, InfantNo, RoomNo)
    VALUES(@Stat, @FirstName, @LastName, @Address, @Cities, @States, @Countries, @PhoneNos, @EmailId, @PinCode, @CIn, @COut, @AdultNo, @ChildNo, @InfantNo, @RoomNos)
END
```

Please help me fast as possible...Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: @Rahul Sign : Thank You....My Problem solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception message is self explanatory, the number of parameters you are passing does not match with that of number of parameters defined in your Stored Procedure. But, hold on the SP you have posted and the code both have equal number of parameters, but your SP definition is on `Hotel` database:-

```
USE [Hotel]
```

While you are hitting `Test` database from your form:-

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=AMAR;Initial Catalog=Test;
                              Integrated Security=True";
```

So, you need to point to the same DB where correct SP is deployed:-

```
Initial Catalog=Hotel;
```

Apart, from this as a side note, Consider using the [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement to dispose your expensive database resources automatically and use `Add` instead of `AddWithValue`, read this [Article](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Ty ,Changed, but still have an error - String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @AmarS.Gawade - Still have an error but that's a different one :) This error means there is any column in your DB whose length is less than the respective data you are passing. For example, say your `Address ` column is defined as `nvarchar(100)` but you might be passing the text which exceeds 100 characters, so increase its value in DB.